# MSAL. Detect revoked permissions and perform re-authorization

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal

In current MSAL version `1.1.0-alpha0277` there are some changes from official release `1.0.304142221-alpha`. One of them is the changed exceptions codes (class `Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.MsalError`).

In `1.0.304142221-alpha` when I try to call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync()` and user has revoked his permissions, I received `MsalException` exception with code:
`Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.MsalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently`.
I could catch them and call `AcquireTokenAsync()` for re-authorization with UI. But now, I don't know how to detect such situation.

What exception code should I use in `1.1.0-???` builds for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should catch MsalUiRequiredException. It would indicate that you should take the developer to interactive flow